# Google Colab runs on a folder out of "My Drive" folder

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am doing an online course and i use Colab for the assignments.
The initialization code is given to me, so all i need to do is to run it and start to code.

The problem is that for some reason Colab decided to separate one folder- **"cs231n"**. I can still see this folder in the tree on the left under "My Drive", but when calling functions that i write there in the bottom one (i write in .py files), from the .ipynb notebook, nothing happens. like the .py file doesn't exist.

But when writing the code in the separated folder, which is not under "My Drive" (the upper one), .ipynb works fine.

So i do my assignments with the upper cs231n separated folder, but it is a twisted way to go...

**The actual path in my drive:**
[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLNy7.png)

**The Colab initialization and the folders-tree:**
[colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReT0u.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you give me more details.

Comment: What would you like to know?